# MySQL find all periods of given length without related record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making a booking system in PHP/MySQL.

I want to be able to select a month, select a booking length, and find how many periods of the given length are available (ie, not marked as booked) within that month.

I started by creating a table of days, each day has a field that indicates if it's reserved or not, as well as a date. The two tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `day` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `booking` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `booking` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

So far I've been able to count how many days in a month *aren't* booked - but that doesn't necessarily tell me if say there are 7 days in a row:

```
SELECT  
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as year,
    EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date) as month,
    count(day.id)
FROM
    day
WHERE booking IS NULL
GROUP BY year, month
```

At this point I'm considering loading all the days for my given month, and iterating through them in PHP to make up my numbers, but it seems kinda dumb and inefficient. Does anyone have a suggestion how I can find this information directly from MySQL?

Comment: It depends. If it's easier for you to solve the problem in PHP, you could do that. One month is not that much data and creating periods might better work in your script than in the database. However if you're willing to step deeper into SQL and Mysql you might learn how to do all or part of your work already inside the database which normally is pretty well on data handling.

Comment: This works as well: `SELECT  
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date) AS year_month,
    count(day.id)
FROM
    day
WHERE booking IS NULL
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want ranges of at least 7 days in July, 2012, then:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d') start,
  MAX(days) AS days,
  DATE_FORMAT(start + INTERVAL MAX(days) - 1 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d') end
FROM (  
  SELECT
    d2.`date` start,
    (@days := IF(IFNULL(d2.booking, 0) = 0, @days + 1, 1)) AS days
  FROM
    (SELECT @days := 1) a,
    day d1
  LEFT JOIN  
    day d2 on d2.`date` = d1.`date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  WHERE
    IFNULL(d1.booking, 0) = 0
) d1
GROUP BY
  start
HAVING
  (
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM start) = 201207 OR
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM (start + INTERVAL MAX(days) - 1 DAY)) = 201207
  ) AND
  days >= 7
ORDER BY
  start
```

will produce this output:

```
|      START | DAYS |        END |
----------------------------------
| 2012-06-25 |   13 | 2012-07-07 |
| 2012-06-26 |   12 | 2012-07-07 |
| 2012-06-27 |   11 | 2012-07-07 |
| 2012-06-28 |   10 | 2012-07-07 |
| 2012-06-29 |    9 | 2012-07-07 |
| 2012-06-30 |    8 | 2012-07-07 |
| 2012-07-01 |    7 | 2012-07-07 |
| 2012-07-23 |    8 | 2012-07-30 |
| 2012-07-24 |    7 | 2012-07-30 |
```

The clause

```
(  
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM start) = 201207 OR
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM (start + INTERVAL MAX(days) - 1 DAY)) = 201207
)
```

is used to include all ranges, even if the range extends into the previous, or next month. If you want ranges that fall exclusively in a single month, use:

```
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM start) = 201207 AND
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM (start + INTERVAL MAX(days) - 1 DAY)) = 201207
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e36a/4 for an interactive demo.

Comment: This looks about as close as it gets to a pure MySQL answer, and extending into next month is ridiculously useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date) AS year_month, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM day
LEFT JOIN booking ON booking.start <= day.date + INTERVAL 6 DAY
                  AND booking.end >= day.date
WHERE booking.start IS NULL
GROUP BY year_month
```

The idea is that you're looking for those rows from `day` where no row from `booking` overlaps with the 7-day range starting at that day.